# Avoiding Multiple Queries when Searching for Records Associated with a Set of Records

Tags: mysql

So, I am sure I have done something really stupid while designing this, and I'm open to schema changes if they'll really help me out.

On to the problem:

I have a custom shopping cart system (backed by a MySQL database) that includes a `products` table and a `price_rules` table that's used for computing discounts and applying promo code discounts. Some price rules don't have promo codes attached to them; some are simply "10% off of product X from March 1st through April 1st" or similar. Because a single price rule can apply to many individual products, I also have a join table called `price_rule_product`.

When showing a set of products (for example, on the main shop page or listing all products in a category) I'm currently running a separate query for each product to look for price rules that apply to that product. Here's what one of those queries looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    price_rule.* 
FROM 
    price_rule
    INNER JOIN price_rule_product ON
        price_rule.id = price_rule_product.price_rule_id
    INNER JOIN product ON
        product.id = price_rule_product.product_id
    WHERE product.id = 10
        AND price_rule.apply_to = 'line_items'
        AND (  price_rule.start_date IS NULL
            OR price_rule.start_date = 0
            OR price_rule.start_date <= 1366063902 )
        AND (  price_rule.end_date IS NULL
            OR price_rule.end_date = 0
            OR price_rule.end_date >= 1366063902 )
        AND (  price_rule.promo_code IS NULL
            OR price_rule.promo_code = '' )
    ORDER BY 
         sort ASC
```

Oh SQL Gods, I pray you have some suggestions/solutions for this. It is causing some significant performance issues, and I'm just not experienced enough with SQL to figure out where to go from here.

EDIT: Here's the output of EXPLAIN SELECT both with and without DISTINCT:

WITH DISTINCT

```
id  select_type table               type    possible_keys   key key_len ref                         rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          product             const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 3   const                           1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          price_rule      ALL         PRIMARY         NULL    NULL    NULL                            14  Using where
1   SIMPLE          price_rule_product  eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 8   craft_art.price_rule.id,const   1   Using where; Using index; Distinct
```

WITHOUT DISTINCT

```
1   SIMPLE          product             const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 3   const                           1   Using index; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          price_rule      ALL         PRIMARY         NULL    NULL    NULL                            14  Using where
1   SIMPLE          price_rule_product  eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 8   craft_art.price_rule.id,const   1   Using where; Using index
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is commonly overused, and seems unnecessary here... it may be hurting performance my requiring the server to take extra steps to ensure distinctness of a result-set that shouldn't contain duplicates.  Consider posting the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT` of the query... with and without the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: ETA the output from EXPLAIN SELECT with and without DISTINCT

Comment: You can also remove the join to `product` and use the condiiton `WHERE price_rule_product.product_id = 10`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display the products regardless if they are associated with a price rule, right ?
In my opinion, you'd best achieve this with an `OUTER JOIN`, which will give you all products and simply return an empty `PriceRuleId` column for the products without price rules.

The following query will give you a result Matrix with all products and their price rules, if they have them.

```
select 
     p.id as ProductId
    ,pr.id as PriceRuleId
    ,pr.apply_to as PriceRuleApplyTo
    ,pr.start_date as PriceRuleStartDate
    ,pr.end_date as PriceRuleEndDate
    ,pr.promo_code as PriceRulePromoCode
from
    products p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN price_rule_product prp ON prp.product_id = p.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ( SELECT id, apply_to, start_date, end_date, promo_code
            FROM  price_rule
            WHERE 
                apply_to = 'line_items'
                AND ( start_date IS NULL OR start_date = 0 OR start_date <= 1366063902 )
                AND ( end_date IS NULL OR end_date = 0 OR end_date >= 1366063902 )
                AND ( promo_code IS NULL OR promo_code = '' )
            ) pr ON prp.price_rule_id = pr.id
```

I hope I understood the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT price_rule.* 
  FROM price_rule
    INNER JOIN price_rule_product 
       ON price_rule.id = price_rule_product.price_rule_id
      AND price_rule.apply_to = 'line_items'
      AND COALESCE(price_rule.start_date, 0)  <= 1366063902 
      AND ( COALESCE(price_rule.end_date, 0) = 0 
            OR price_rule.end_date >= 1366063902 )
    INNER JOIN product 
       ON product.id = price_rule_product.product_id
      AND product.id = 10
      AND COALESCE(price_rule.promo_code, '') = '' 
    ORDER BY sort ASC
```